# How to link OpenSSL library in macOS using gcc?

Tags: osx, gcc, libraries, openssl, linker

I have OpenSSL installed through the Homebrew package manager.  I have found the library and header files I need.

The headers are:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2h_1/include/openssl
/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2j/include/openssl
/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2k/include/openssl
```

The library files are:

```
/usr/lib/libssl.0.9.7.dylib
/usr/lib/libssl.0.9.8.dylib
/usr/lib/libssl.dylib
```

I've tried several `gcc` commands to try to link the OpenSSL library, including:

```
gcc md5.c -I/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2k/include -lssl
gcc md5.c -I/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2k/include -llibssl
gcc md5.c -I/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2k/include -llibssl.dylib
gcc md5.c -I/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2k/include -llibssl.0.9.8
gcc md5.c -I/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2k/include -llibssl.0.9.8.dylib
```

All of them produce either a "File not found" error or a linker error.

What's the proper way to do this?

Comment: Does homebrew put a `*.pc` package config file for it anywhere?

Comment: @thrig I found several:    

    /usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2h_1/lib/pkgconfig/libcrypto.pc
    /usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2h_1/lib/pkgconfig/libssl.pc
    /usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2h_1/lib/pkgconfig/openssl.pc
    /usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2j/lib/pkgconfig/libcrypto.pc
    /usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2j/lib/pkgconfig/libssl.pc
    /usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2j/lib/pkgconfig/openssl.pc
    /usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2k/lib/pkgconfig/libcrypto.pc
    /usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2k/lib/pkgconfig/libssl.pc
    /usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2k/lib/pkgconfig/op...

Comment: You'll probably either need to do a `brew switch ...` to "activate" one of those openssl versions, or with `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` set to include one of those `pkgconfig` directories you could do `pkg-config --cflags --libs openssl` to get the necessary flags for compile.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to link against the openssl libraries installed with your os, rather than the homebrew libraries.  Try to find where homebrew installed the 1.0.2k libraries.

```
find /usr/local/Cellar/ -name "libssl.*"
```

You should find something like /usr/local/Cellar/_path_of some_sort/libssl.a.  Try to link against this library rather than the ones in /usr/lib.  The /usr/lib libraries are old and not compatible with the header files you are using.

```
gcc md5.c -I/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2k/include -L/usr/local/Cellar/path_of_some_sort/ -lssl -lcrypto -o md5
```

Comment: Specifically, the following worked for me: `gcc -Wall -g  -L/usr/local/Cellar//openssl@1.1/1.1.0g/lib/ -I/usr/local/Cellar//openssl@1.1/1.1.0g/ -lcrypto -o urtorrent urtorrent.o bencode.o metainfo.c filestring.o`